# Update p:inputMask component itself on p:ajax keyup without losing its value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, input-mask, ajax-update

I have a PrimeFaces `<p:inputMask>` component.

Its mask needs to be changed depending on associated listener.

```
<p:inputMask id="creditCardMask" 
             value="#{controllerCard.creditCard.creditCardNumber}" 
             mask="#{controllerCard.creditCardType.creditCardType}">

                <p:ajax event="keyup" 
                        process="@this keyCodePressedInInput"
                        update="creditCardImage creditCardMask creditCardInput"
                        listener="#{controllerCard.listenerCardNumber}" />
</p:inputMask>
```

If the credit card is an AMEX, mask need to be for example : `999-999`, but if this is a MasterCard, it should be `999-999-999`.

So I need to update the component itself using `keyup` ajax event, but it is reset on every request from the listener to the backing bean.

How can I keep the value of the input text?

Comment: `update="creditCardMask"`renders the whole control, thats a reset. You should try to solve it in Javascript.

Comment: @Holger: why is that a reset? The ajax calls has a process of '@this`, so it should submit the existing value to and an update of the component itself should contain that new value. (Disclaimer: at least that is what I'd expect. I never used a construction like this, so I'm not sure)

Comment: Hmm, now, you writing it, that may be right. But I would try it in Javascript. I wouldn't like an Ajax-call and page update with every keystroke.